# Kubeadm won't pull images (unable to determine version and cri-dockerd not found)

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I did fresh install for several Ubuntu 22.04 servers with the latest (1.24.3) kubeadm, kubelet, and kubectl installed. I am also using **containerd** as the CRI.

The error happens when I was trying to initiate the K8s cluster by running the preflight:

```
# kubeadm config images pull --kubernetes-version=v1.24.3 --v=5
I0808 04:27:08.139042  475778 initconfiguration.go:117] detected and using CRI socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
I0808 04:27:08.139530  475778 interface.go:432] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0808 04:27:08.139580  475778 interface.go:437] Default route transits interface "ens160"
I0808 04:27:08.140022  475778 interface.go:209] Interface ens160 is up
I0808 04:27:08.140168  475778 interface.go:257] Interface "ens160" has 2 addresses :[10.0.1.12/8 fe80::250:56ff:fe83:e1e3/64].
I0808 04:27:08.140231  475778 interface.go:224] Checking addr  10.0.1.12/8.
I0808 04:27:08.140271  475778 interface.go:231] IP found 10.0.1.12
I0808 04:27:08.140307  475778 interface.go:263] Found valid IPv4 address 10.0.1.12 for interface "ens160".
I0808 04:27:08.140344  475778 interface.go:443] Found active IP 10.0.1.12 
I0808 04:27:08.140415  475778 kubelet.go:218] the value of KubeletConfiguration.cgroupDriver is empty; setting it to "systemd"
exit status 1
output: time="2022-08-08T04:27:08Z" level=fatal msg="unable to determine image API version: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/cri-dockerd.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
, error
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime.(*CRIRuntime).PullImage
        cmd/kubeadm/app/util/runtime/runtime.go:121
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.PullControlPlaneImages
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:340
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdConfigImagesPull.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:312
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.24.3"
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.PullControlPlaneImages
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:341
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdConfigImagesPull.func1
        cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/config.go:312
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

Obviously, the output is compaining version was not found and cri-dockerd was not found. This shouldn't be the case since I explicit specified the kube version and at the beginning of the output, and it was also be able to find the containerd at the beginning.

cri plugin has already disabled in `/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
# cat /etc/containerd/config.toml|grep cri   
disabled_plugins = ["cri"]
```

I am new to k8s so not sure what is wrong with it. I was followed the k8s doc from the beginning, not sure what is missing: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't disable the cri plugin.

Please remove `cri` from that section then restart the containerd.

```
disabled_plugins = []
```

And it's better to add `cri-socket` option to every kubeadm command just in case:

```
kubeadm <commands> --cri-socket=/var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Comment: I was using the Docker repository for installing the containerd. The cri plugin was disabled by default and should be removed. Thanks!